# How to eliminate fields with same data from result in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
  body: {
         "query": {
           "bool": {
             "filter": [
               {
                 "bool": {
                   "should":[
                     {
                       "bool":{
                         "must":[
                           {
                             "term":{
                               "company_id.keyword":req.token.company_id
                             }
                           }
                         ]
                       }
                     },
                     {"bool":{
                         "must":[
                           {
                             "term":{
                               "company_id.keyword" : -1
                             }
                           }
                         ]
                       }
                     }
                   ]
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         },
         "aggs": {
           "menu": {
             "terms": {
               "field": "service_menu.keyword"
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

Hello !

I'm using this query , and as a result I have all the service_menus with id 1 and -1 and thats great.

I realized in my data that one of the "service_menu" with id 1 is the same as "service_menu" for id -1(both of them are named Pasta). In that case I want the service_menu to be showed in my result only once.(Pasta to be showed in my result only once) What should I add in my case ? Thank you all for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You can try [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub aggregation here.
Please note I haven't tested query. But this should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id.keyword": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id.keyword": -1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "menu": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "service_menu.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "document": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```